# Apache2: Getting wrong root directories

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I am having a slight apache problem.  It's probably something so minor that I am just over looking it.  This is the scenario.  I have an Ubuntu 10.04 server setup with 2 websites.  Before all of this, I had one site and I accessed it via the IP address.  I just added a second site, this one with a domain name, and I created a new file in the sites-available dir. with a link to the sites-enabled dir.

The first site (the one I accessed via IP) config looks something like this:

```
#Default
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
......etc
```

Then the other config is something like this:

```
#Secondary 
<VirtualHost TheDomainName.com:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/thedomainname
.......etc
```

If you guys need me to post the full config files I will.  Why does the request for the IP address fall through to the DomainName config? Is it because they are identical IP addresses?  How do I differentiate between the two?

If I try to set the ip address on the first "Default" config instead of "*", this site only works and I can never get to the other "Secondary" site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For site1:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName oink.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  ...
```

For site2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName blah.domain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/thedomainname
   ...
```

Comment: The trick is the ServerName (and ServerAlias if you want more aliases for the same virtual host) directives. The first virtual host defined will be the catch all for all other sites/hostnames/etc. pointed towards it.

Comment: OK Thanks, I was using the domain name in the second <VirtualHost> directive.  I am using * for both now and setting the ServerName/ServerAlias instead.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ServerName and ServerAlias in your virtual host directive?

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  www.domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com domain.net www.domain.net
```

The other thing, and you are probably doing this, but restarting apache after making changes

httpd restart

(or something similar .. /etc/init.d/apache2 restart or lighttpd if you are  using that)

Answer (score 1):

Different sites cannot share IP and port combination unless you use [name based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/name-based.html). The example from the manual is this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.otherdomain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

When you use this feature, unknown domain names map to the first `<VirtualHost>` found in your configuration.